# What problems arise if user-space drbd is older than the kernel module?

Tags: centos6, xen, drbd

Since more than five years I am using XEN in a productive environment.

My constellation: SLES11 (included: OpenSource XEN 4.x), DRBD 8.3 in primary/secondary mode.

Now I would have loved to go away from SLES to RedHat or CentOS, but sadly there was no xen-Dom0-support in the major-release 6 any more.

This has changed with a CentOS6-branch that developed an alternative repository (XEN4) with a version 3 kernel and XEN 4.x. Now the kernel-module included with that kernel is a drbd-module 8.4 (no extra rpm needed!).

Many of my scripts work with DRBD 8.3 and need to be re-written for 8.4. since the CLI has changed a lot between these versions.

In this constellation the drbd-user-space rpm (drbd-utils) comes from elrepo in flavours for 8.3 and 8.4.

My idea: Use the drbd83-utils (so I still have the old CLI syntax) with the 8.4 kernel module. Are there any major drawbacks to be expected?

OR: Alternative: Replace 8.4 with 8.3 by using an older kmod-drbd83?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work. Apart from some warnings there are stuck low-level commands as well.